# How do I model a real life observation with mathematical expression or equation(s)?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, applications

I am looking for a guide to learn how to model real life situations into mathematical equations and able to simulate them.

My target is to able to understand and interpret something I observe into a mathematical equations sot hat I can simulate it on a piece of paper of a computer.

I have Studied Engineering Mathematics in my college level, but that catered only the purpose of clearing the examinations only.

Any guide which will tell me how to do the selection of branch with examples or exercises will be appreciated.

Comment: There are any number of textbooks on applications of mathematics that are full of examples of deriving equations from situations. Do you have access to a library?

Answer (score 0):

You might find that [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/0521679710) is helpful. There might even be a copy online. However, I suppose it should be said that there's no one-size-fits-all way of approaching applications: it very much depends on what you're trying to understand.